# BiFunction Object in Map's compute method

Tags: java, function, java-8, hashmap

I want to create a BiFunction object(Lambda), and use it in a Map's compute method. It will compile correctly, but it will throw NullPointerException at runtime.

```java
private BiFunction<String, Integer, Integer> biFunctionWithAddition(final Integer addition) {
        return (model, quantity) -> model == null ? addition : quantity + addition;
    }

hashmap.compute(i, biFunctionWithAddition(1)) //throw NullPointerException


//the one that can work should be:
hashmap.compute(i, (num, quantity) -> num == null : 1 ? quantity + 1);
```

Comment: Are you sure `model == null` shouldn't be `quantity == null`?

Comment: Thanks, you are right. Changed to quantity == null, and it worked.

Comment: But it’s simpler to use `hashmap.merge(i, 1, Integer::sum);` which is equivalent to `hashmap.merge(i, 1, (a, b) -> a + b);`, so no dealing with `null` necessary.

Comment: @Holger, thanks! Help me a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compute method is called also if the key is not in the map, so you can create the value for the key.
So in your case this happen:

```
hashmap.compute("KEY_NOT_IN_MAP", biFunctionWithAddition(1));
```

will call your lambda function like this:

```
("KEY_NOT_IN_MAP",null) ->KEY_NOT_IN_MAP" == null ? addition : null + addition;
```

so you can see key(model) is not null so the second part of the ternary operator will be evaluated and will fail with NPE because of this: `null + addition;`

your quantity in lambda is null.